# Integrate NULL check in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, null

I have a list of parts in `partList`. I want to get the `Name` of a part by filtering the `Number`. Something like

```
var foundPart = partList.Where(part => part.Number == 1).SingleOrDefault();
if(foundPart != null)
    name = foundPart.Name;
```

Can I eliminate the `null` check and put everything in the LINQ command?

Comment: I would stick with the current null check, much more readable than anything else based on null-coalescing operator IMHO.

Comment: Can't you do this in your initial creation of partList?

Comment: @ken2k actually I also like simple `if`, `foreach` etc, and use them when it is possible. Because it's very simple to understand. And I believe that code which is easy to understand is the best code

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string name = partList.Where(part => part.Number == 1)
                      .Select(part => part.Name) // project result here
                      .SingleOrDefault();
```

If you want to avoid changing name when no match found:

```
name = partList.Where(part => part.Number == 1)
               .Select(part => part.Name)
               .DefaultIfEmpty(name)
               .Single();
```

NOTE: I like LINQ, but in this case I would simplify your query a little and keep *if* condition. Very clear and simple to understand:

```
var part = parts.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Number == 1);

if(part != null)
   name = part.Name;
```

Comment: This would set null to "name"; currently the OP doesn't update "name" if there is no result.

Answer (score 2):

What happens if `foundPart` is `null`?

If you're ok with `name` being null:

```
var name = partList
             .Where(part => part.Number == 1)
             .Select(part => part.Name)
             .SingleOrDefault();
```

If you want to set it to something else, use the null-coalescing operator:

```
var name = partList
             .Where(part => part.Number == 1)
             .Select(part => part.Name)
             .SingleOrDefault() ?? "Default Name";
```

If you don't want to touch `name` at all, then there's no way to simplify what you already have.

Answer (score -1):

You can just use .FirstOrDefault() instead of .SingleOrDefault()

```
var foundPart = partList.Where(part => part.Number == 1).FirstOrDefault() ?? "Default";
```